# Obtaining data from user

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-views

How do I obtain the field data from a User auth query within a class View. It's on the django 2.2.x framework using Python3

This code works just fine...

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PaymentsReportView(ListView):
    template_name = 'payments/Payment_list.html'
    userid = 'James'
    queryset = Payment.objects.filter(Landlord_FK__User_id=userid)
```

but this doesn't...

```py
class PaymentsReportView(ListView):
    template_name = 'payments/Payment_list.html'
    userid = User.username   # where the username is James
    queryset = Payment.objects.filter(Landlord_FK__User_id=userid)
```

How can I check the output of User.username to see if it's valid? What am I missing to get the data? The code doaen't break. It just returns empty.

Comment: print it or display it in the view and see if its "James" or "james". Or maybe is something else.

Comment: How would I do this? I should clarify that I am able to display the correct username elsewhere, just not within this class.

Comment: `printing = lambda x: print(x) or x`; then use `printing(userid)` in an expression. (`print` returns `None`, so the value of the `printing(x)` expression will always be `x`). _Of course_ this is crude.

Comment: this is on your view right? Then go to the html page and just display the variable {{request.user.username}}

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I need it to work within this class. The username displays correctly otherwise

Comment: My question is rather how to display "userid" rather than user.username

Comment: ah cool ok try adding def __init__() in the PaymentsReportView class and print it there to console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that at class level. What you need to do is to define a `get_queryset` method and do the filtering there:

```
class PaymentsReportView(ListView):
    template_name = 'payments/Payment_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        userid = self.request.user.username
        return Payment.objects.filter(Landlord_FK__User_id=userid)
```

Although I must note that this implementation is odd; why is the userid the username, rather than the ID? Usually I would expect the filter to be `(Landlord_FK=request.user)`. You should show your models.

Comment: I agree it's probably a more awkward implementation than it needs to be and I may well change it to the more conventional way. In the meantime, it doesn't seem to like "request"

Comment: Sorry, should have been `self.request...`, updated.

Comment: That is indeed the solution. Many thanks. I have learned a lot from this.